# Write a program in c++ that output a matrix as below

Tags: c++

This is what it has to look like but mine it's turned on the other side

```
00001
00021
00321
04321
54321
```

And please explain it to me if you can.

It said that I have to add more details so I am writing this don't know what for.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t=0,n,tab[100][100]={0},k,j,a;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        k=i;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(j<=i)
                tab[i][j]=k+1;

            k--;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cout<<tab[i][j]<<"   ";

        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your specific issue?

Comment: Looks like a good case for using a debugger.  When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?

Comment: Your code is not using the `time.h` or the `cstdlib` include files.

Comment: Why do you need the `k` variable?  You can substitute `i` for `k` inside the `j` `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches: one that uses standard algorithms and functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>


int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int a[N][N] = {};

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::iota( std::reverse_iterator<int *>( a[i] + N ), 
                   std::next( std::reverse_iterator<int *>( a[i] + N ), i + 1 ), 
                   1 );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and other that uses only loops

```
#include <iostream>


int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int a[N][N] = {};

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 1; j <= i + 1; ++j ) a[i][N - j] = j;
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The both program outputs are

```
0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 2 1 
0 0 3 2 1 
0 4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1
```